# Has anyone used react-native-firebase"v6" + firebase cloud messaging + react-native-push-notification(library) in sync?

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I have been trying to pull of this combination since a few weeks but I'm not able to.

I have been looking for various tutorials but they all are for react-native-firebase v5.

If you have used this combination successfully then please explain how did you do it?
Thanks

Comment: There is no update on using RN Notifications in v6! As of now, it is remove from the release. Read this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2566

Comment: I know, that’s why I asked how can we integrate react-native-push-notification library!